# How to strengthen induction hypothesis in Coq proof?

Tags: coq, formal-languages

I'm trying to formalize applicaion of context-free grammars in practice task. I have problems in proving one lemma. I tried to simplify my context to outline the problem, but it is still a bit cumbersome.

So I defined CFG in Chomsky normal form and derivability of list of terminals as follows:

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Inductive ter : Type := T : nat -> ter.
Inductive var : Type := V : nat -> var.
Inductive eps : Type := E : eps.

Inductive rule : Type :=
  | Rt : var -> ter -> rule
  | Rv : var -> var -> var -> rule
  | Re : var -> eps -> rule.

Definition grammar := list rule.

Inductive der_ter_list : grammar -> var -> list ter -> Prop :=
  | Der_eps : forall (g : grammar) (v : var) (e : eps),
      In (Re v e) g -> der_ter_list g v []
  | Der_ter : forall (g : grammar) (v : var) (t : ter),
      In (Rt v t) g -> der_ter_list g v [t]
  | Der_var : forall (g : grammar) (v v1 v2 : var) (tl1 tl2 : list ter),
      In (Rv v v1 v2) g -> der_ter_list g v1 tl1 -> der_ter_list g v2 tl2 ->
        der_ter_list g v (tl1 ++ tl2).
```

I have objects that store terminal and some additional info, for example:

```
Inductive obj : Set := Get_obj : nat -> ter -> obj.
```

And I try to define all possible lists of objects, which are derivable from given nonterminal (with helper functions):

```
Fixpoint get_all_pairs (l1 l2 : list (list obj)) : list (list obj) := match l1 with
    | [] => []
    | l::t => (map (fun x => l ++ x) l2) ++ get_all_pairs t l2
  end.

Fixpoint getLabels (objs : list obj) : list ter := match objs with
    | [] => []
    | (Get_obj yy ter)::t => ter::(getLabels t)
  end.

Inductive paths : grammar -> var -> list (list obj) -> Prop :=
  | Empty_paths : forall (g : grammar) (v : var) (e : eps),
      In (Re v e) g -> paths g v [[]]
  | One_obj_path : forall (g : grammar) (v : var) (n : nat) (t : ter) (objs : list obj),
      In (Rt v t) g -> In (Get_obj n t) objs -> paths g v [[Get_obj n t]]
  | Combine_paths : forall (g : grammar) (v v1 v2 : var) (l1 l2 : list (list obj)),
      In (Rv v v1 v2) g -> paths g v1 l1 -> paths g v2 l2 -> paths g v (get_all_pairs l1 l2).
```

(Each constructor of `paths` actually corresponds to constructor of `rule`)

And now I'm trying to proof fact about `paths` by induction, that every element in `paths` can be derived from nonterminal:

```
Theorem derives_all_path : forall (g: grammar) (v : var)
  (ll : list (list obj)) (pths : paths g v ll), forall (l : list obj),
        In l ll -> der_ter_list g v (getLabels l).
Proof.
  intros g v ll pt l contains.
  induction pt.
```

This construction generates 3 subgoals, 1st and 2nd I've proved by applying `Der_eps` and `Der_ter` constructors respectively.
But context in 3rd subgoal is not relevant to prove my goal, it has:

```
contains : In l (get_all_pairs l1 l2)
IHpt1 : In l l1 -> der_ter_list g v1 (getLabels l)
IHpt2 : In l l2 -> der_ter_list g v2 (getLabels l)
```

So `contains` means that `l` is concatenation of some elements from `l1` and `l2`, but premises in `IHpt1` and `IHpt2` are true iff `l2` and `l1` has empty lists, which is not true in general, so it is impossible to prove goal with this context.

The problem can be resolved if `l` in `contains`, `IHpt1`, `IHpt2` will be different lists, but unfortunately I don't know how to explain it to Coq. Is it any way somehow change `IHpt1` and `IHpt2` to prove the goal, or any other way to prove the whole fact?

I tried to look on `paths_ind`, but it didn't make me happy.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your induction hypothesis is not strong enough. If you perform `induction pt` on a more polymorphic goal, you'll get more useful hypotheses not tied to the specific `l` you started with.

You should try:

```
intros g v ll pt; induction pt; intros l contains.
```